# UITabBarNavigation Does not Fire in viewWillApear in IOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I'm using Tab bar navigation in my app and it was working fine.
On iOS 8 I found that the page is loaded and (`viewDidLoad`) got fired .. but `ViewWillAppear` is not got called neither `ViewDidAppear`.

I Tried to delete the View Controller Sague between the tab bar controller and my viewController, And recreated it again.. but still no use..

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: restart Xcode (if you are testing in Simulator) :)

Answer (score 0):

In my app it works fine, it called when I select special tab

Answer (score 0):

You may use the tabbar controller delegate :

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```